# Keras: Accuracy stays zero

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras

I am trying to get into machine learning with Keras.

I am not a Mathematician and I have only a basic understanding of how neural net-works (haha get it?), so go easy on me.

This is my current code:

```
from keras.utils import plot_model
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras import optimizers
import numpy

# fix random seed for reproducibility
numpy.random.seed(7)

# split into input (X) and output (Y) variables
X = []
Y = []
count = 0

while count < 10000:
    count += 1
    X += [count / 10000]
    numpy.random.seed(count)
    #Y += [numpy.random.randint(1, 101) / 100]
    Y += [(count + 1) / 100]
print(str(X) + ' ' + str(Y))

# create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(50, input_dim=1, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(50, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation='sigmoid'))

# Compile model
opt = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])

# Fit the model
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=150, batch_size=100)

# evaluate the model
scores = model.evaluate(X, Y)
predictions = model.predict(X)
print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
print (str(predictions))
##plot_model(model, to_file='C:/Users/Markus/Desktop/model.png')
```

The accuracy stays zero and the predictions are an array of 1's. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I can see you are trying to solve a regression problem (floating point function output) rather than a classification problem (one hot vector style output/put input into categories).

Your sigmoid final layer will only give an output between 0 and 1, which clearly limits your NNs ability to predict the desired range of Y values which go up much higher. Your NN is trying to get as close as it can, but you are limiting it! Sigmoids in the output layer are good for single class yes/no output, but not regression.

So, you want your last layer to have a linear activation where the inputs are just summed. Something like this instead of the sigmoid.
    `model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='lecun_normal', activation='linear'))`

Then it will likely work, at least if the learning rate is low enough.

Google "keras regression" for useful links.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are attempting to do binary classification, with a `binary_crossentropy` loss function. However, the class labels `Y` are floats. The labels should be 0 or 1. So the biggest problem lies in the input data you are feeding the model for training.

You can try some data that makes more sense, for example two classes where data are sampled from two different normal distributions, and the labels are either 0 or 1 for each observation:

```
X = np.concatenate([np.random.randn(10000)/2, np.random.randn(10000)/2+1])

Y = np.concatenate([np.zeros(10000), np.ones(10000)])
```

The model should be able to go somewhere with this type of data.

Comment: Isn't there a way to make float predictions?

Comment: Yes you can. You need to change loss function to something like mean square error. Check this: [](https://keras.io/losses/). Also, you probably want to remove the sigmoid activation in the last layer...

Comment: Okay, I got it to work. But the loss decreases by teeny tiny steps, almost none. What kind of network with wich parameters would you recommend?

Comment: It is hard to say. One thing to do would be to do training on a small subset of dataset and overfit it (loss near 0). You can try two things: Different learning rates for the optimizer, and different optimizers. Most optimizers will probably work better than SGD.

Comment: Change the LR parameters of the optimiser you are using - SGD in your example. Adam is a good default optimiser rather than SGD.