# Keras Neural Net returning only 0.00e+00 for accuracy when training

Tags: python-3.x, neural-network, keras

I'm trying to run a neural net in which the input data has a shape of (116, 2, 3*58) and the output has a shape of (116, 2, 1). The goal is, when 2 teams of 3 individuals from a given list of 58 individuals are put against each other, to predict the scores of each team.

The input array represents 116 matches, 2 teams per match, 3 individuals on each team, each individual one-hot encoded to a binary array of length 58 (all 0.0 except 1.0 at the index of the team in the list of labels). The output returns the expected scores of each team. The scores range from 0 to 600.

However, when I train the net, the accuracy always returns 0.00e+00. What am I doing wrong? I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46642627/keras-accuracy-stays-zero) but it didn't change anything.

Here is my code:

```
def ec(val, labels):
    return [1.0 if x == val else 0.0 for x in labels]

lb = open("labels.txt")
labels =  [line.replace("\n", "") for line in lb.readlines()][::3]

trainingInput = np.load("trainingInput.npy")
trainingOutput = np.load("trainingOutput.npy")
trainingInput.resize(116, 2, 3*58)

pprint(list(trainingOutput))


inp = Input(batch_shape=(None, 2, 3*58))
d1 = Dense(16, activation='relu')(inp)
d2 = Dense(32, activation='relu')(d1)
out = Dense(1, activation='linear')(d2)

model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=out)
lrSet = SGD(lr=0.00001)

model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer=lrSet, metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(trainingInput, trainingOutput, batch_size=8, epochs=50, verbose=1, validation_split=0.1)

test = np.array([np.array([np.array([ec(sys.argv[0], labels), ec(sys.argv[1], labels), ec(sys.argv[2], labels)]), np.array([ec(sys.argv[3], labels), ec(sys.argv[4], labels), ec(sys.argv[5], labels)])])])
test.resize(1, 2, 3*58)

print(list(model.predict(test)))
```

Comment: Your network is doing regression, and accuracy is completely meaningless in regression problems, its only valid for classification.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Ah, I see. In that case, I'm still getting really low values when I try to predict (in the single digits, as compared to the hundreds in the training data). Is there anything I can improve in the network?